# No funciona el top-0 ni el left-0 en Tailwind con posicion absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, tailwind

Estoy teniendo un problema debido a que no funciona el top-0 ni el left-0 para posicionar un elmento arriba a la izquierda, estoy trabajando con Tailwind y Django.

Codigo de la sección del problema:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>

<div class="flex-shrink-0 relative">
  <div class="absolute top-0 left-0">
    <lottie-player src="https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_rZQs81.json" background="transparent" speed="1"
      style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" loop autoplay></lottie-player>
  </div>
  <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="https://www.womantimes.cl/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/FLotBHjWYAQr77o.jpg"
    alt="Neil image">
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar la corona (la que tiene la posicion absolute) solo queda en la posición del centro.

Les agradecería si me pudieran ayudar, ya que no logro ver lo que esta mal :(

Comment: Tienes que colocar un ejemplo reproducible

Comment: Simplemente usa por ejemplo `-top-3` en el div que envuelve al `lottie-player` y veras que funcionará.